# ¿Cómo mostrar un componente específico de un QComboBox en Python (PyQt5) teniendo el índice?

Tags: python, json, pyqt5, combobox

estoy llenando un Qcombobox usando un archivo JSON, el cual se ejecuta sin problemas. Luego de esto agrego un valor adicional usando additem=("") para que la lista de este combobox inicie en una posición vacía, yo ejecuto un proceso de guardado en una base de datos (también lo ejecuto sin problemas). Lo que quiero es que después que se ejecuto ese proceso el combobox se sitúe en el índice cero(0). (no quiero borrar el combobox) solo quiero que no muestre nada pero sin borrar los datos

comparto el código que carga los datos del archivo JSON

```
def cargar_datos(self, ruta):        
        self.departamento = 0        
        with open(ruta) as colombia:
            self.todos_los_departamentos = json.load(colombia)            
            self.cmbDptos.addItem("")
            for self.departamento in self.todos_los_departamentos:                
                self.cmbDptos.addItem(self.departamento.get('departamento'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `setCurrentIndex(index)` para asignar un índice al combobox

```
self.cmbDptos.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Comment: gracias a tu aporte pude solucionar el inconveniente.